# Systemd Kernel Variables Error

Tags: boot, kernel, services, systemd

At boot, I receive an error message `[failed] failed to start apply Kernel variables`. I have not used a Systemd distro until now so I'm not sure what I should be looking for.

I ran this in terminal and got the following:

```
systemd-sysctl.service - Apply Kernel Variables
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-sysctl.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-04-30 13:40:13 EDT; 26min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysctl.service(8)
           man:sysctl.d(5)
  Process: 546 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 546 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 30 13:40:13 ced-XPS-8700 systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
Apr 30 13:40:13 ced-XPS-8700 systemd[1]: systemd-sysctl.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 30 13:40:13 ced-XPS-8700 systemd[1]: Failed to start Apply Kernel Variables.
Apr 30 13:40:13 ced-XPS-8700 systemd[1]: systemd-sysctl.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 30 13:40:13 ced-XPS-8700 systemd[1]: systemd-sysctl.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```